# valid parameters to pandas method

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas seems to ignore the extra (invalid) parameters. For e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', some_dummy_param=True)
```

I expected **(but did not get)** an error something like ...

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'some_dummy_param'
```

The problem is, since there is no error, I consider "some_dummy_param" to be valid. This is certainly not expected. Is there any way to make sure only valid parameters are passed to read_excel method?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same parameters across different read functions in pandas?

Comment: Pandas take keyword arguments **kwds as an argument in read_excel function, that's why it is not throwing error. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really.

Keyword arguments are often passed in Pandas through [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python), which is either forwarded or treated as a `dict`. The functions that use this `dict` are free to check if there are keys other than those they expect or not.

You *could* do something like:

```
def safe_read_excel(self, f_name, *args, **kwargs):
    # Check if kwargs contains wrong parameters
    if set(kwargs.keys()).difference(set(<expected keys>)): 
        raise ValueError(<some messagge>)
    return self.read_excel(f_name, *args, **kwargs)

pd.DataFrame.safe_read_excel = safe_read_excel
```

However, this would

1. create a non-standard method for DataFrame
2. possibly break for different versions of Pandas

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this isn't going to be a trivial problem to solve. `pd.read_excel` accepts `**kwargs` in its signature. This means that you can pass whatever keyword arguments you please, because `read_excel` is not going to do anything with keyword arguments that it doesn't *need* to use.

One way of approaching this problem is to

1. Determine what keyword arguments `read_excel` *actually* accepts
2. Build an argument list for `read_excel`
3. Filter out invalid arguments based on the results of (1)
4. Pass the filtered argument list to the function

To handle (1), you can use the `inspect` module to determine what arguments `pd.read_excel` accepts. In particular, the `inspect.signature` method returns a `Signature` object from which you may query the `parameters` attribute. This returns a `mappingproxy` (effectively an immutable dictionary).

```
import inspect
args = inspect.signature(pd.read_excel).parameters

print(args)
mappingproxy({'convert_float': <Parameter "convert_float=True">,
              'converters': <Parameter "converters=None">,
              'date_parser': <Parameter "date_parser=None">,
              'dtype': <Parameter "dtype=None">,
              ...})
```

Here, it is assumed (2) is already done. However, in your case, you will need to ensure your potential parameters are inside a dictionary, as this will make it *really* easy to intersect on the mappingproxy and filter.

```
params = {'io' : 'myfile.xlsx', 'some_dummy_param' : True}
```

Step (3) involves performing a set intersection on the keys, and then rebuilding a new parameter list *only* from the intersection.

```
valid_params = {k : params[k] for k in params.keys() & args.keys()}

print(valid_params)
{'io': 'myfile.xlsx'}
```

This forms your valid argument list—the basis for (4).

```
df = pd.read_excel(**valid_params)
```